# jQuery Mobile events - standalone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the jQuery Mobile events(https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.event.js) to work as a standalone "plugin" but I can't seem to figure out what I need to change.

I know this is possible because I used this: https://gist.github.com/743400 in the past and it worked... that file is based on beta or even alpha release of JQM and I would like to use the latest... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**
You can now build a custom package for jQuery mobile 1.2 http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/ and select the Events that you need for your project

---

The following worked for me for jquery mobile 1.1-stable branch:

1. clone the repo from github https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile
2. git checkout 1.1-stable
3. edit the Makefile on line 131 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/1.1-stable/Makefile#L131 to build jquery.mobile.event instead of jquery.mobile
4. run `make js` to compile the modules necessary for events
5. the built versions will be available in the `compiled/` folder