# jQuery mobile events but without the UI

Tags: jquery-mobile, event-handling

Is there a (simple) way to get the events functionality of jQuery mobile without any of the UI elements?

This is for upgrading a set of already written UI components to play nice in a mobile environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile events - standalone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417624/jquery-mobile-events-standalone) You could also detect if the browser supports touch events (e.g. with Modernizr) and then bind to touch events for mobile devices and regular events for non-mobile devices. I like to do this because the `event` object in a touch event handler has some interesting information, like how many touches are occurring at once (i.e. is the user zooming or scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `data-role=page` since those are what the JQM events are fired for.

For rest of the elements within the page you can prevent JQM from styling them using the `data-enhance=false` flag.

Read the [Enhancement Section](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/data-attributes.html)

From JQM Source

```
// The current version exposes the following virtual events to jQuery bind methods:
// "vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel"
```

You should be able to bind to all these just like any other events using live/on/delegate

Comment: I can see how this would be true for page related events, but is this also the case for events like `tap` or `vmousedown` and so on ?

Comment: so I want to clarify - must I have an element with data-role=page to use vmousedown?

Comment: o.k. - tested - at least in a normal browser you don't actually need the page to use jquery events such as vmousedown.
http://jsfiddle.net/epeleg/g2AP9/